# page loads recursively when calling the templateURL

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

I am using angular full stack generator and created a directive. When I am using the templateUrl, the whole page is recursively loading. But when I try include the html using the template, it works correctly. Any way how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did mis-configure your template URL and angular is not loading your template but the index.html, which causes the loop. Check your template URLs and the server routing.